# How do I close internet tabs with python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-webbrowser, gtts

Hello I am using gtts speech recognition and get audio to create a voice assistant like Alexa (this is why I named her Alex) and I am working on searching the web using the webbrowser module. Here it opens a website that says the weather in my location. Does anyone know how I can close this tab using python after a while?
If it is any help I am using raspberry pi duckduckgo and chromium. Thank you.

```
    while True:
          if get_audio() == 'hey Alex':
            search = get_audio()
            if search == 'what is the weather':
                dest='https://weather.com/en-GB/weather/today/l/f71eff26206918c09bd0cf032da3d10774f5f10b16a35a30d41e258cc2397c8e'
                web.get(path).open(dest)
                if get_audio() == 'thank you Alex':
                    text_to_read = 'no problem'
                    reading_from_string()
```